# What is the meaning of 'acala sukha'?

Tags: terminology

What is the exact meaning of '*acala sukha'*? Is it mentioned in the Pali-canon? If so, where ? In what context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PTS dictionary](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.1:1:1424.pali) says,

> **Cala** (adj.) [see calati] moving, quivering; unsteady, fickle, transient S iv.68 (dhammā calā c' eva vyayā ca aniccā, etc.); J ii.299; iii.381; v.345; Miln 93, 418; Sdhp 430, 494.
>   -- **acala** steadfast, immovable S i.232; J i.71 (ṭṭhāna); Vv 514 (˚ṭṭhāna=Ep. of Nibbāna); acalaŋ sukhaŋ (=Nibbāna) Th 2, 350; cp. niccala motionless DhA iii.38

So *cala* means "unsteady", *acala* means "not unsteady", and *acala sukha* means "unwavering happiness" i.e. nibbana.

The phrase is in some of the suttas, e.g. the last line of [Ud 8.10](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.8.10.than.html); and the end of the first verse of [Thag 3.16](https://suttacentral.net/en/thag3.16).

Comment: +1 with one caveat, sukha is rather something like "peace", the (quiet) state of no trouble, than a rapturous type of happiness. Maybe "nonquivering peace"...

Comment: I hoped the OP would already know *sukha* (see e.g. [PTS definition here](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.4:1:262.pali) and [Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukha)).

Answer (score 0):

Stuffs turn Vaṭṭa on (vaṭṭa) = appearing stuffs in paṭiccasamuppāda  = non stopping cycling of stuffs = **anicca (unstable) & dukkha** = **cala (unstable)** = **whole 5 aggregates** (stuffs)

Stuffs turn vaṭṭa off (vivaṭṭa) = disappeared stuffs in paṭiccasamuppāda = stopped cycling of stuffs = **niccatā (stable) & sukkha** = **acala (stable)** = **nibbāna**

Whole 5 aggregates and nibbāna are anatta.